# Checking if the optimizer support gradient

Tags: openmdao, scipy-optimize

I want to distinguish optimizers (gradients based and free). If I use the sample optimization in the main webpage of [OpenMDAO](https://openmdao.org) which uses SLSQP and check if the optimizer supports gradients I get "False" as in;

```
prob.driver.supports['gradients']
```

is this OpenMDAO or Scipy related issue?

Is there another way to see if the optimizer will use the gradient calculations or not before the problem is run.

---

Based on the answer below I added this in the beginning of my script; Thanks!

```
    prob = om.api.Problem()
    prob.driver = user_driver_object
    prob.setup()
    prob.final_setup()
    grads.append(prob.driver.supports['gradients'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `ScipyOptimizeDriver` not all optimizers support gradient optimization, hence you cannot determine the correct value until you setup your driver This is done in `final_setup()` of your problem (which calls `_setup_driver()` in your driver). This method is called in `run_model()` and `run_driver()`, but you can also call it in itself to get the correct properties of your optimizer.

In the example below I am asking the driver 3 times if it supports gradients. The first time, after the *problem* setup it gives a False answer (the default), because the driver was not touched yet. If I call `final_setup()`, this will setup the driver, and all the properties of the driver will be correct. If `run_model()` or `run_driver()` is called, of course this will also setup the driver.

So my advice is to just use `final_setup()` before querying anything from your driver, that can change during the setup (which are mostly optimizer specific properties).

```
import openmdao.api as om

# build the model
prob = om.Problem()
indeps = prob.model.add_subsystem('indeps', om.IndepVarComp())
indeps.add_output('x', 3.0)
indeps.add_output('y', -4.0)

prob.model.add_subsystem('paraboloid', om.ExecComp('f = (x-3)**2 + x*y + (y+4)**2 - 3'))

prob.model.connect('indeps.x', 'paraboloid.x')
prob.model.connect('indeps.y', 'paraboloid.y')

# setup the optimization
driver = prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('indeps.x', lower=-50, upper=50)
prob.model.add_design_var('indeps.y', lower=-50, upper=50)
prob.model.add_objective('paraboloid.f')

prob.setup()
print("\nSupports gradients (after setup)?")
print(prob.driver.supports['gradients'])

prob.final_setup()
print("\nSupports gradients (after final setup)?")
print(prob.driver.supports['gradients'])

prob.run_driver()
print("\nSupports gradients (after run)?")
print(prob.driver.supports['gradients'])
```

This results in the following output:

```
Supports gradients (after setup)?
False
Supports gradients (after final setup)?
True
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -27.33333333333333
            Iterations: 5
            Function evaluations: 6
            Gradient evaluations: 5
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
Supports gradients (after run)?
True
```

Comment: Ok thanks for this. I was hoping to fix a problem in an automated manner but I won't be able to it seems. Sometimes my problem size is too big to set full Jacobians (some components I have to use 'fd' approximation which populates the full Jacobian). So I have a flag in the setup() of each component that in case a gradient-free optimizer is selected the partials wont be declared. (otherwise it wont fit into memory). But then this flag is set with respect to the selected optimizer gradient support. (which I can not know before setting my problem)

Comment: i will fix this by setting up a dummy problem with user given optimizer and then checking the dummy problems "support gradient" and then setting up my own components with respect to that

Comment: If you would like to go this way, making a dummy problem is indeed a solution. Making a dummy driver, and calling `_setup_driver()` or importing the  `_gradient_optimizers` from `scipy_optimizer` and checking if your optimizer is in the list also does the job. Since both are private, these are a bit dirtier solutions.